# Mule ESB functional tests, passing in a collection instead of a String

Tags: mule

Question on functional tests; I have a test that calls a Mule flow gets an output and asserts that output as per particular values. Here is the code.

```
MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
MuleMessage reply = client.send("vm://someFlow", "abcdef", null);
assertNotNull(reply);
assertNotNull(reply.getPayload());
String result = (String)reply.getPayload();
assertEquals(result,"300 xyz");
```

Basically I pass in the value `abcdef` & it returns the correct value `300 xyz` which I duly assert.

Now if I have to modify the configuration and the use case such that in the configuration I have a number of values that need to be collected as part of an 'All' flow control & I want to return all of them & assert them individually . For example here are the sample values:

```
abcdef returns 300 xyz
badads returns 400 jhk
caddad returns 100 uik
```

Obviously I need to pass in a collection & on the return I need to assert the collection , how can I possibly modify my JUnit to assert these individual values?

Comment: MuleClient does not take only string params, but Object, so you can send whatever java object your want, such as a List or whatever.

Same with the return value, currently you cast to String but you can as easy cast to whatever collection type you have.